# Why does print give different output with and without newline?

Tags: arrays, perl

I am getting two different results with and without new line character in the `print` statement of regular expression match. why?

```
$string16="abfoo bcfooo defooo ghfooo ijfoo klfooo mnfooo";
@foo=$string16=~ m/foo/g;
print(@foo);
print("\n");

$string17="abfoo bcfooo defooo ghfooo ijfoo klfooo mnfooo";
@foo=$string17=~ m/foo/g;
print(@foo."\n");
```

result:

```
foofoofoofoofoofoofoo
7
```

Answer (score 13):

Because you are using the concatenation operator `.`, which forces `@foo` into *scalar context*. Arrays return their number of elements in scalar context.

Use an argument list instead of the concatenation with your `print` to get the list and the newline. The array `@foo` will be expanded to the list it contains anyway, so the newline will just be another argument to `print`.

```
print @foo, "\n";
```

As an alternative, you can use [`say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html), which needs to be activated with `use feature 'say'`. It removes the need to append newlines when printing. `say` is available from Perl 5.10.

```
use feature 'say';
say @foo;
```

You can also turn it on with

```
use v5.10;
```

This has nothing to do with the regular expression. It's a core behavior of Perl, and how lists in Perl work.

[Here's a good explanation](http://perl.plover.com/context.html) of what context means in Perl.

Comment: The proper line ending is linefeed on every platform. It is PerlIO that converts between that and the nat8ve line endings on input and output.